# In a DatePicker in Vaadin Flow, how to get the invalid value?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

I really need the invalid field value ("today", "last week monday" etc) in the DatePicker (https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/components/date-picker).

How is it possible to retrieve the arbitrary text in a DatePicker field?

[image]

---

After asking question I found this, but not sure if there a better way:

```java
submitDate.getElement().executeJs("return this.inputElement.value;"
            ).then(value -> {
                String val = value.asString();
                
                // do whatever you need with 'val'
            });
```

Comment: This is an upcoming feature in Vaadin 24.3 or 24.4.  Meanwhile you need to use the JavaScript workaround you found.